# How to cancel email activities in crm 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am trying to cancel email activities of a entity in Dynamics CRM 2011. but when i am trying to cancel a selected activity, it is showing me a pop up such that "you can not perform this action on email activities". and also can you tell me how to cancel email activities using workflows or something else instead doing it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, is their any reason why you can't delete it rather than marking it cancelled?

But if you still want to keep it cancelled rather than delete then, The Status of an email can be set to Competed or Cancelled via workflow, dialog or plugin.

It can be done by creating an on-demand workflow as following.

[image]

You can run this workflow by clicking on `Run Workflow` button on ribbon. It will be visible after selecting the record. If you want to set the status to cancelled on create (based on any rules), in that case write a plugin.

Comment: ya i have tried it. but when i am choosing other than Email in entity field i am not able to choose Email in workflow step. and also i am unable to run it as child work flow also if i choose other entity in Entity field..

Comment: You can only see the Main Entity and related entities in list available on Parent workflow. I would recommend you to write a `Code Activity` or `Plugin` to update the status then. What is the scenario, can you explain your properly so that I can try to answer you better. I believe I have already answered the question you have asked initially.

Comment: There are some scheduled open email activities in a request form. so on some condition i need to create some new email activities or send mails to user and i need to cancel old email activities which already scheduled. i am able to send mails to user using workflows. but i am not able to delete or cancel the old activities which are already schedule using workflows. can you help me in this?

Comment: Write a `CodeActivity` and run it from workflow after or before creating new Email Activity. In `CodeActivity` write code to search the old email and update the status of that email or even you can delete email as well. Let me know if its making any sense, otherwise I will try to explain in detail.

Comment: CodeActivity means do i need to  write C# Code? I have tried to access email activities from my C# code also.. but i am able to access all properties in my entity. but i am unable to access email activities from my entity.. Can you please provide me some references?

Comment: @NaveenGupta I believe I have already answered your question. If you want to know how to write an Workflow activity then start a new thread please. You might find some existing threads as well.

Comment: ya i am doing that one only. Here problem is, My main workflow is working on Requestform Primary Entity. and My child workflow which is for cancelling emails is running on Email Primary entity. so i am not able to choose child workflow in main workflow. If i choose RequestForm as primary entity in child work flow, then i am able to link main workflow and child workflow but in this case i am unable to cancel emails from child work flow..

Comment: How to Create Custom Workflow Activity and use in workflow : http://mscrmbasics.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/crm-2011-how-to-create-custom-workflow.html  That's all I can help you without expecting a single upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to create a child workflow from main workflow? Try may helps you to relate those..